# ASP.NET MVC app is slower after few days

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, razor

We have running ASP.NET MVC 3 project on one site...

Application is used by 6-8 users simultaneously.

Users reports, that after some days of using, application is much slower. We have to restart IIS, and after that, it works fine.

We did not recorded some dramatic increase of memory usage.
We also follow articles about ASp.NET performance (remove engines, add only razor, release mode, we are caching third party libraries in GAC, ...)...
We are not caching data ([OutputCache] attribute).

For temporary data holding we are using session.

Do you have any idea, what can slow down application after few days? Or how we can profile it?

Comment: Are you using any database access in your application? Are you disposing of your connections to the database properly? Have you forgotten to dispose of any other resources in the `Dispose()` of your methods?

Comment: How are you profiling memory usage? Just by looking at the Performance window in Task Manager? App pools have limits, you should check your processes, find the w3wp.exe process with the User Name of your site, record the memory used, and compare that with the limit of your app pool.

Comment: You can turn on SQL logging to view the queries sent to database and see where is the bottle neck. You can also use mvc-mini-profiler for this purpose: https://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/

Comment: I removed the thanks and regards from your post as the concensus is that posts don't need that http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/158100

Comment: Thanks for comment. We are using PostgreSQL database. I checked active connections. They are not increasing. We are disposing EF container at the end of request. Memory is checked on w3wp process. We will check that profiler.